# Rails 4 public 404/500 error pages are requesting image resources with bad paths

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, asset-pipeline

I've built some error pages (404, 500, etc) into the public folder of my app. I know these are outside of the asset pipeline, so I built each as a stand alone html file, with CSS in the head.

These error pages have a couple images (a background and a logo). Both are loaded the usual way (not using any rails helpers):

```
<img src="Checklick-Logo-White-Transparent.png" alt="Checklick Logo" style="width: 100%">

background: url("Checklick-Cloud-Background-High.jpg") no-repeat center top;
```

On production, when I try to load these pages (`app.checklick.com/500.html`), they load just fine.

However, when I get an *actual error* on the app, and those same error pages are loaded, for some reason, the image paths get a controller name appdended to them (ie they become `app.checklick.com/programs/Checklick-Logo-White-Transparent.png`). The controller then tries to perform an action using that image filename as an argument, which causes yet another error. And of course, the browser can't render either images, so the error pages themselves look broken.

Any idea how/why the controller name would be added to the image request during an actual error?

Comment: I would suggest you compare the rendered html in both cases (directly entered using the 500.html url, and generating the 500 error via your app) using the browser debug console. In a true 500 server error situation the Rails action controller is not actively routing (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-default-500-and-404-templates)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out, all that was wrong was that I wasn't using a root-relative path to the images on my public 404/500 html pages.

I changed

```
<img src="Checklick-Logo-White-Transparent.png" alt="Checklick Logo" style="width: 100%">
```

to

```
<img src="/Checklick-Logo-White-Transparent.png" alt="Checklick Logo" style="width: 100%">
```

and changed

```
background: url("Checklick-Cloud-Background-High.jpg") no-repeat center top;
```

to

```
background: url("/Checklick-Cloud-Background-High.jpg") no-repeat center top;
```

Now, no matter what the source of my error pages, the images load OK. For example, I can load app.checklick.com/500 or app.checklick.com/programs/500 and still load the images OK.

Answer (score 2):

Images should be in `app/assets/images` directory.

in public page you can write path like -

```
<img src="/assets/Checklick-Logo-White-Transparent.png" alt="Checklick Logo" style="width: 100%">
```

Comment: Should images be in the /app/assets/images directory, even when they are being served outside of the asset pipeline (as in my example - error pages)?